# How I can import data from URL by using output of GoogleCustomSearch?

Tags: text, webmathematica, hyperlink, word-cloud, url

I am trying to make a word cloud from all URLs that are as outputs after using google custom search so I  think I need to read those URLs as data or text to can make a word cloud

this is code just you need to add API and search ID

```
CS = ServiceConnect["GoogleCustomSearch"]

rs1 = ServiceExecute["GoogleCustomSearch", 
  "Search", {"Query" -> "Architecture", 
  "Site" -> "https://www.archdaily.com/", MaxItems -> 5}]
```

. [image: that is what I mean]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please post code, not images. It is not clear what you are trying to do. Do you mean you want to `Import` the plaintext from the link in the `Link` column and create a wordcloud from those words?

Comment: Well, I updated it now.

Comment: yes, I mean import data as text from the Link in the column and create a word cloud from those data @RohitNamjoshi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

To generate a `WordCloud` from the combined plaintext

```
rs1[All, "Link"] // Normal // Map[Import[First@#, "Plaintext"] &] // 
   StringJoin // DeleteStopwords // WordCloud
```

---

Try this

```
wc[link_] := Import[First@link, "Plaintext"] // DeleteStopwords // WordCloud

rs1[All, "Link"] // Normal // Map[wc]
```

Comment: it's worked thanks so much just I need to collect them as a one-word cloud. @RohitNamjoshi

Comment: @MayAlyAwad Answer updated to show combined `WordCloud` generation.

Comment: it's worked well thank you so much I appreciate this...

Comment: @MayAlyAwad You are welcome.